# Displaying data from MongoDB (MEAN Stack)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am trying to displaying some data from a Mongo DB onto the front-end. I am working with the MEAN stack, which I'm relatively new at.

I have successfully gotten the data to display in JSON format at a localhost URL (localhost:3030/incidents), but cannot get the clean data to appear on the front end (which is at localhost:9000).

This is what my code looks like so far for the server side (*router.js*):

```
"use strict";

var config = require('../config/database-config');

var Router = function (options) {
  var self = this;
  self.environment = options.environment;


  self.route = function(app) {
    var IncidentController = require('./controllers/incident-controller.js');
    var IncidentModel = require('./models/incident-model.js');
    var incidentModel = new IncidentModel(config[`${self.environment}`]);
    console.log("Incident Model", incidentModel);
    var incidentController = new IncidentController({model: incidentModel});

    app.get('/api/incident/:id', incidentController.findIncidentById);
    app.get('/incidents', incidentController.getAllIncidents);
  };
  return self;
};

module.exports = Router;
```

**Client side:**

*services.js:*

```
'use strict';
    angular.module('victimList.services', []).factory('Victim', function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost:3030/api/incident/:id');
    });
```

*data.js:*

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('victimList', [])
   .service('victimList')
   .controller('DataCtrl', ['victimService', function ($scope, victimService) {
      victimService.getVictims(function(victims) {
        $scope.victims = victims;
      });
}])
  .factory('victimSerivce', function($http) {
    var getVictims = function(callback) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:3030/incidents').success(function(data){
        callback(data);
      });
    };

    return {
      getVictims: getVictims
    };
  });
```

*app.js:*

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('frontendApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'victimList',
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/victims', {
        templateUrl: 'views/victims.html',
        controller: 'DataCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'victims'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

*victims.html:*

```
<div ng-app="victimList">
  <h1>Testing</h1>
    <div ng-controller="DataCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="victim in victims">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>{{ victim.firstname }} {{ victim.lastname }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When I navigate to the localhost:9000/victims page, I get the header tag, but no data. The console shows this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: victimServiceProvider <- victimService <- DataCtrl
```

What could I be missing? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You are missing the scope in your DataCtrl before the function call.

Comment: You have a typo. You named your service `victimSerivce` and in your controller you are referencing `victimService`. :)

Comment: @MatthewGreen, how would I add the scope?

Thanks, @ex0dm3nt!! I've fixed the typo, but now it's showing the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getVictims' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I needed to add the following:

```
angular.module('victimList', [])
   .service('victimService')
   .controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', 'victimService', function ($scope, victimService) {
      victimService.getVictims(function(victims) {
        $scope.victims = victims;
      });
}])
```

^^ Note that '$scope' was added on line 3.